# How to scrape data based on selection of two drop downs with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data where the table appears after selection of two drop down values. I.e. select dropdown 1, dropdown 2 populates, select dropdown 2, table populates. I want to scrape the table for every value of each. However, my current code just iterates through dropdown 1, doesn't wait and doesn't select anything in dropdown 2.

Any ideas on what I'm getting wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("url")

dropdown1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"dropdown1_id"))
dropdown2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"dropdown2_id"))

data = {}

for option1 in dropdown1.options:
    # Select the option in the first dropdown menu
    dropdown1.select_by_value(option1.get_attribute("value"))

    # Wait for the second dropdown menu to update
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dropdown2_id")))

    # Iterate through each option in the second dropdown menu
    for option2 in dropdown2.options:
        # Select the option in the second dropdown menu
        dropdown2.select_by_value(option2.get_attribute("value"))

        # Wait for the table to update
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "table-loading-spinner")))
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "table_id")))

        html = driver.page_source

        df = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"id": "table_id"}, flavor='bs4')[0]

        data[(option1.get_attribute("value"), option2.get_attribute("value"))] = df

driver.quit()
```

Comment: can we have the url?

Comment: Is that `dropdown 1` is team and `dropdown 2` is player? please add one snapshot how the select display as a result?

Answer (score 3):

You should give more time for the dropdowns to load. I suggest you use `EC.visibility_of_element_located` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located` and wait for the dropdowns to load the options with a custom wait.

You should also skip the first option in every dropdown since they are just a placeholder.

```
class __WaitForOptions:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.__target = target

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return len(self.__target.options) > 1


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://footystatistics.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

dropdown1 = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "teams_dropdown"))))
wait.until(__WaitForOptions(dropdown1))
data = {}

for option1 in dropdown1.options[1:]:
    # Select the option in the first dropdown menu
    dropdown1.select_by_value(option1.get_attribute("value"))

    # Wait for the second dropdown menu to update
    dropdown2 = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "players_dropdown"))))
    wait.until(__WaitForOptions(dropdown2))

    # Iterate through each option in the second dropdown menu
    for option2 in dropdown2.options[1:]:
        # Select the option in the second dropdown menu
        dropdown2.select_by_value(option2.get_attribute("value"))

        # Wait for the table to update
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "table-loading-spinner")))
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "player_match_stats_2018")))

        html = driver.page_source
        df = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"id": "player_match_stats_2018"}, flavor='bs4')[0]
        data[(option1.get_attribute("value"), option2.get_attribute("value"))] = df

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few notes...

It's better to create the WebDriverWait object outside the loop and reuse it, as creating it multiple times. Also, you might need to reinitialize the dropdown2 object after selecting an option from dropdown1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://footystatistics.com/")

dropdown1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "dropdown1_id"))

# Initialize WebDriverWait object outside the loop
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

data = {}

for option1 in dropdown1.options:
    # Select the option in the first dropdown menu
    dropdown1.select_by_value(option1.get_attribute("value"))

    # Wait for the second dropdown menu to update
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dropdown2_id")))

    # Reinitialize the dropdown2 object after selecting an option from dropdown1
    dropdown2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "dropdown2_id"))

    # Iterate through each option in the second dropdown menu
    for option2 in dropdown2.options:
        # Select the option in the second dropdown menu
        dropdown2.select_by_value(option2.get_attribute("value"))

        # Wait for the table to update
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "table-loading-spinner")))
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "table_id")))

        html = driver.page_source

        df = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"id": "table_id"}, flavor='bs4')[0]

        data[(option1.get_attribute("value"), option2.get_attribute("value"))] = df

driver.quit()
```